# Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except number 13

Tags: arrays, list

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.

my code:

```
def sum13(nums):
  sum1 = 0
  for i in nums:
    sum1 += i

  if 13 in nums:
    ind = nums.index(13)

    if ind == len(nums)-1:
      sum13 = sum1 - 13 
    else:
      sum13 = sum1 - 13 -nums[ind+1]
    return sum13

  else:
    return sum1
```

it fails when

```
nums= [1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13]
```

Comment: making it clear, you don't want the sum to include all 13?

Comment: or you want it the summation to stop when it reaches 13?

Comment: I want exclude number 13 and the number that come immediately after number 13.
for example if A = [2,4,5,13,5,7]
number 13 and 5 will be excluded from the summation

Comment: What have you figured out during your debugging?  This is a small enough function that it's a great candidate to learn how to debug if you don't have any experience yet.

Comment: The above code works perfectly  if there is only one number 13, it exclude number 13 and  it's successor. The problem arises when there is more than one number 13 in the list.
let say for A= [2, 1, 13, 4, 1, 2, 13, 3, 2]  it will only eliminate 13 & 4 and return 24 but it should eliminate 13&4 and 13&3 and return total of 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your list, if you want to find the sum of all numbers other than 13, try:

```
sum( i for i in nums if i!=13)
```

Now if you want to stop the summation when you reach your first 13 in the list, try:

```
sum( i for i in nums[:nums.index(13)]  if i!=13)
```

Now to exclude 13 and the number after that from summation, try:

```
def sum13(nums):
    if nums[-1] == 13:
        return sum([nums[0]] + [nums[i] for i in range(len(nums)) if (nums[i] != 13 and nums[i-1] !=13)])
    else:
        return sum([nums[i] for i in range(len(nums)) if (nums[i] != 13 and nums[i-1] !=13)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum13(nums):
    sum=0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i]!=13:
            sum+=nums[i]
        elif i<len(nums)-1:
            if nums[i+1]!=13:
                sum-=nums[i+1]
        
    return sum
```